# How to deploy grails project

Tags: tomcat, deployment, grails

I have copied grails project war file in

`tomcat/webapp`

Then i give its url in browser as

```
http://localhost:8080/LCPRLogViewer-0
```

I am getting 404 error as,

```
The requested resource (/LCPRLogViewer-0.1/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/logSelector/logSelector.jsp) is not available.
```

Why is that so??

Comment: Can you confirm that this app works in your dev environment?

Comment: ya it works in dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

Check your tomcat manager to ensure that the app at that context (`/LCPRLogViewer-0.1`) deployed successfully!

Your next step will be to try deploy the dev war on your local tomcat and confirm that that works too.

"`grails dev war`" or "`grails -Dgrails.env=development war`"

If that does work then the problem lies in your production settings.

Comment: ya it is.then also i am not getting.

Comment: Even that is not working.its going to controller but not view why.

Comment: I have set in conf file server url in production as, asgrails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}".still what else i need to do.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change any settings in your tomcat environment. Can you get a clean tomcat and throw the war file onto it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with one of my Grails projects.  In my case, it was because I did not execute "grails install-templates" prior to building the WAR.  I know this probably comes too late for the original poster, but hopefully this will help others who run into this issue.